Cool tropics, colder poles
Basically, a simplified version of a question I asked before.
I've seen lots of questions on tropical poles and icy equators, but I'm only interested in a cool equator. I don't need the poles to be boiling. In fact, I'd prefer them cold.
I just want an Earth that's colder than now without being an snowball Earth. The idea is to put most landmasses close to the equator and then a larger one spanning most of the planet further North, much like Siberia but with vast areas within the temperate band.
The issue is space: the Ice Caps will increase in size and I need to know just how much space will end up temperate. World is otherwise the same as Earth.

What makes you think that this is any better than your previous question, where you got the comment:"there's simply too many variables to give you an answer "?

If it isn't scientifically accurate, at what moment would this be a problem with your story? To have details be scientifically accurate is nice, but if you want to write a story with a hollow Earth that has a star inside, no one will bat an eye. Next is whether it is relevant to talk about it in your story. Where in your story would you need to divulge this information, or is it enough that it is just there? A comment that the poles are cool instead of cold can be enough. If your book becomes popular, there will be people finding solutions for you.

@Trioxidane it's sort of important to establish it takes place in a version of our universe, mostly because I'm determined to marry (semi-hard, FTL is obviously purely SpecFi) hard sci fi with fantasy... not by doing an Star Wars or Dune, but essentially taking our current technology and science and "maxxing them out" to the point where they'd be "burning money" in our world, but doable in this one where the money supply is controlled by someone. Having a geography that makes at least partial sense helps add to the story without invoking Suspension of Disbelief.

@L.Dutch Even assuming we're dealing with an exact replica of Earth (the details are added IF anyone thinks it'd be easier to try with those, which I doubt). Unfortunately, I assembled the world in pieces, which means the whole doesn't really mesh well together unless I go full fantasy land, and that's something I'm determined to avoid.

Are you actually wanting tropics as such, noting that they are a consequence of axial tilt?  There is nothing stopping you having a planet with negligible axial tilt, which means that the warmest part of the planet (which can still be quite cool, compared to Earth) is at the equator and temperatures simply decrease with distance from the equator.  (You can still have seasons, if you wish, but the mechanism would be a significantly eccentric orbit rather than axial tilt.)

Dumb luck or divine agency brought your world significant volcanic CO2 outgassing just in time to avert Snowball Earth. Now the glaciers are retreating and the deserts bloom with life watered by glacial runoff.  Well-fed and carefree children frolic in the meadows of an ever-longer summer, whose grandparents grew up expecting the world to die in the grim starvation of a winter that would never end.
(Alternately, your characters expect the world to die in the grim starvation of a winter that grows a little longer every generation, and one day will never end.)

@g s  That could actually work. Dumb luck is still possible (it doesn't have to be plausible as long as it can happen), especially if the effects are confined to a rather small area... and I've run into the problem that led to me asking the question; just how much space would I have, if this world where just Earth, down to geography (minus the extra volcanism).

There are too many variables at play, especially without a very detailed map of your world (including ocean circulation patterns etc...), to give you a really solid answer.
You, knowing more of those details, can start making some educated guesses by looking climate map estimates around the Last Glacial Maximum on Earth.
As I recall temperate zones are in extremely short supply in a glacial world, the deserts expand north and ice caps expand south both at the expense of temperate biomes. The tropics remain the tropics but are drier due to the general lack of precipitation globally.
I also recommend to all worldbuilders the work of Artifexian, particularly when it comes to climate modelling.

For the sake of simplicity assume it's our world essentially, just colder due to more distance from the star/higher albedo (uniformly, since I don't think we've had losses/increases in just some areas that were significant enough).
